# addEventListener on AppNavItem

Tags: event-handling, vaadin, onclicklistener, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I am using latest version of Vaadin.
Intended: want to catch an event if AppNavItem (with child elements) is clicked (expanded, toggled).

Code:

```
    @JsModule("@vaadin-component-factory/vcf-nav")
    @Tag("vcf-nav-item")
    public class AppNavItem extends Component {

        public AppNavItem(String label) {
            setLabel(label);
        }

        public AppNavItem setExpanded(boolean value) {
            if (value) {
                getElement().setAttribute("expanded", "");
            } else {
                getElement().removeAttribute("expanded");
            }
            return this;
        }

        public AppNavItem setIcon(Component icon) {
            icon.getElement().setAttribute("slot", "prefix");
            int iconElementIndex = getIconElementIndex();
            if (iconElementIndex != -1) {
                getElement().setChild(iconElementIndex, icon.getElement());
            } else {
                getElement().appendChild(icon.getElement());
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
```

```
    AppNavItem myItem = new AppNavItem("Project");

    myItem.addAttachListener(e -> {
        System.out.println(e.toString()); // works on page load as expected !
    });
    //projectParent.onEnabledStateChanged(false); // does not work
    //projectParent.onEnabledStateChanged(true); // does not work
    myItem.getElement().addEventListener("onchange", e -> {
        System.out.println(e.getType()); // does not work
    });
    myItem.getElement().addPropertyChangeListener("expanded","onchange",  e -> {
        System.out.println(e.getPropertyName()); // does not work
    });
    myItem.getElement().addEventListener("onchange", e -> {
        System.out.println(e.getType());
    });
    myItem.getElement().addPropertyChangeListener("expanded","onchange",  e -> {
        System.out.println(e.getPropertyName()); // does not work
    });
    myItem.getElement().addPropertyChangeListener("expanded", e -> {
        System.out.println(e.getPropertyName()); // does not work
    });

    myItem.addItem(...);
```

I tried several eventTypes like: click, onclick, change, onchange, ontoggle, ...
Unfortunately, almost nothing works, see comment.
What am I doing wrong ?

I expect to catch an event

Comment: Where is the `AppNavItem` class comming from?

Comment: sorry, added class AppNavItem :-)

Comment: AppNav and AppNavItem are still early in development, so they lack some APIs. You can report issues here: https://github.com/vaadin/vcf-nav#readme

Can you tell why you need the event, what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: @Jouni : I have a simple usecase: storing the state into database when clicked so that the user has the same state after relogin. Doing this in an event listener should be self-evident. Coming from Angular where this is a simple task. Nobody else had this requirement before ?

Comment: You can maybe handle that requirement by listening for events from the router (e.g. `AfterNavigationListener`) rather than only reacting to navigation events that happen through the menu.

Comment: Thanks for the use case description. Is it required to store the state after every interaction, or would it suffice if it's stored when the application is closed? I don't remember if there’s a built-in event for that, but you could use the `beforeunload` event, loop through the nav items and check their state. That said, the `AppNavItem.isExpanded()` method is missing. And still, an event would probably still be nice to have.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It would be by far the best solution to store the state after interaction. Many web apps work by this behaviour. For example, what happens if the user closes the browser without log out ? The state would be lost ...